# How embedded CSS in transactional email works?

Tags: magento2, email, css, cache, email-templates

I have a very frustrating issue with the Magento 2 sales order emails.  Through experimentation, I worked out the locations of the many files that are used to comprise these emails.

At some point, I edited what I believe was

```
/app/design/frontend/themefolders/web/source/_email-extend.less
```

to alter the CSS there to check if that makes a difference to the resulting sales emails.

The confusion I have is that sometimes editing this seems to influence the resulting emails, sometimes not.

My question is, how do I clarify for sure wha*t **.less / .css*** files are being used as the source for the CSS that I believe is embedded into emails.  I'm not sure if the normal css that is in the pub/static folders of magento comes into this or not.   Clarification about the exact source files for email css would be great.

Comment: where you able to read this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html#css_preprocess_terms ?

Comment: Yes I had @fmsthird, what I'd like is for someone to clarify in summary how the css is compiled into emails.  I understand the basic idea of how .less files are compiled into the public static folders to produce final css but for emails I am less clear what files are being referenced in the generation of the emails and if the static folder actually has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly looks like a mixture of places

Have you tried viewing the source of one of your emails

A forgotten password email I generated using Luma US theme from the admin pulled this via import statement

```
@import url("http://magento2.docker/static/version1571346637/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/email-fonts.css");
```

So `pub/static`

But then I spotted `blockquote cite{font-style:normal}` which is a bit unusual and easy to search for.

I found this inside

`var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/email-inline.css`

which is built from

`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less`

I've read you can override these

```
Add your custom styles here for common emails: 
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_email-extend.less

Add your custom less variables here for common emails : 
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_email-variables.less

Add your custom styles here for sales emails : 
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less
```

Note: I'm a backend dev.  I won't be able to confirm this for you but logically makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in **[Magento Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#email-styles)** this might be a good read. This explains at least **How to Style Email Templates and how email styles are organized.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to override below two css files from Magento default blank theme to you custom theme and editing those files.

> Magento_Blank_theme_dir/web/css/source/_email-extend.less
>
> Magento_Blank_theme_dir/web/css/source/_email-variables.less

Your custom theme css path will be below

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_email-extend.less

and

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_email-variables.less

and for sales email

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less

you can check this magento devdoc link for reference.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html